# Hue, Solr - Auto Fill of Search Terms

Tags: solr, autocomplete, autosuggest, autofill, hue

In the HUE Solr UI, there is an option to create a Dashboard to Search on an index. The search Field allows auto fill of the Index fieldsNames (as per the below HTML Snippet), but not autofill of Search Terms from the Index of the existing terms.

HTML Code for the Search Box -

```
<input data-bind="clearable: q, typeahead: { target: q, source: $root.collection.template.fieldsNames, multipleValues: true, multipleValuesSeparator: ':', extraKeywords: 'AND OR TO', completeSolrRanges: true }
```

Is there a way to allow Autofill of Index Terms? If anyone has implemented this can you share the code to do the same?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: I don't know about Hue bout autocomplete is built in solr using the suggester componant https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not yet available in the new version of the Search App in Hue: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2983