# Solr Search in Hue - is it possible to disable the auto-fill of field names?

Tags: solr, autocomplete, autosuggest, hue

When typing a query in Solr Search, field names are suggested. They are fetched from the variable {{$root.collection.template.fieldsNames}}:

```
<input data-bind="clearable: q, typeahead: { target: q, source: $root.collection.template.fieldsNames, multipleValues: true, multipleValuesSeparator: ':', extraKeywords: 'AND OR TO', completeSolrRanges: true }, css:{'input-xlarge': $root.query.qs().length == 1, 'input-medium': $root.query.qs().length < 4, 'input-small': $root.query.qs().length >= 4}" maxlength="4096" type="text" class="search-query clearable input-xlarge input-medium x">
```

Is it possible to disable this feature completely?
Another option could be narrowing down the list of suggested field names - is it supported?

[Hue, Solr - Auto Fill of Search Terms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32644762/95) is related, but there the question is about replacing field names auggestions with search terms.

Comment: What would be the goal? Is the autocomplete of fields too noisy?

Comment: I want to simplify the user experience interface and hide the complexity of the Solr collection under the hood.